# how to get data from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [main_categories] => MCAT
            [sucategory] => Chemistry
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [main_categories] => MCAT
            [sucategory] => Physics
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [main_categories] => MCAT
            [sucategory] => Biology
        )

)
```

I want to get `id`, `main_categories` and `subcategory`.
I use `data[0]` it returns only `A`.

Comment: no i can't use json.

Comment: A. that's php not javascript. B. You want to get those properties of which object from the array?

Comment: [{"id":"5","main_categories":"ECAT","sucategory":"Physics"},{"id":"6","main_categories":"ECAT","sucategory":"Chemistry"},{"id":"7","main_categories":"ECAT","sucategory":"Mathematics"}]

Comment: any object from array

Comment: thanks Mosh Feu and Niles Tanner for comment i find a solution. thanks

Comment: @NilesTanner JSON is a lightweight data transport format. It is used to move serialized JavaScript objects over a wire and then de-serialize them. As such, the string must be formatted properly. However, JSON, in no way is a requirement to work with structured data in JavaScript. Saying *If you can't use JSON you can't use JavaScript* makes absolutely no sense. The question was not tagged with JSON. Why did you assume right away that JSON was being used. The object structure shown by the OP does not imply JSON.

Comment: @MoshFeu Please don't ever edit a question's code. By completely rewriting it, you completely remove our ability to understand what the OP is working with and how to help. If you have better code, put it into an answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I edited the question's code because I assumed he meant to write javascript but not php.

Comment: @MoshFeu Then you should have simply asked that in a comment. When you change the code (i.e. fix errors), the rest of the question becomes meaningless and the answers are also meaningless because they are addressing code that isn't really what the OP has. Please see ["Privledges - edit questions and answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) for details on what kinds of things you should be changing.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, Umair wrote it in a comment. See the 3rd comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [

    {
        id: 1,
        main_categories: "MCAT",
        sucategory: "Chemistry"
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        main_categories: "MCAT",
        sucategory: "Physics"
    },

    {
        id: 3,
        main_categories: "MCAT",
        sucategory: "Biology"
    }

];

console.log(data[0])
```